# Is there a way to split angular templates and using only the part I need?

Tags: angular, typescript, templates

I work for a company that have one single plage application that run on 4 different website. For each angular component there is an angular template file and in this file a switch between 4 differents HTML structures to render the same data but differently (one way for each websites)

Obviously the entire code and template for each website is in the single package that run on each websites and only the configuration make it work the good way for each website.

Is there a way to create some sort of areas to partition the angular templates and build a package that contains only the code and template I need for each website ?

An example :

my-component.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as configuration from '../../configuration';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
})
export class MyComponent {
    public template: string;

    constructor() {
        this.template = configuration.template;
    }
}
```

my-component.component.html

```
 <ng-container [ngSwitch]="template">
     <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="t1">
         ...
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="t2">
         ...
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="t3">
         ...
     </ng-container>
     <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="t4">
         ...
     </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Is there a way to create a template file for t1, t2, t3 and t4 and make the component.ts using only the one he needs according the value in configuration ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use *template* (instead of *templateUrl*) and assign different HTML strings depending on your environment.
You might be able to use *html-loader* to import html files as variables.

Comment: html-loader seems to be the good solution for what I want to do ! But it leads me to an issue. I load my template with a template: `require('html-loader!./templates/my-component.${configuration.template}.html')` and it works well because it select the good file, but now I have Template parse errors for every *ng in any elements...